# Copy python modules from one system to another

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-module

Is it possibe to copy all of the python modules from one Windows computer to another computer? They are both running the same version of Python 2.7.12.

The reason for doing so is that I have internet access on one of them, and manual installing modules on the other requires to much time because of dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you mean "copy the python installation from one system to another" (else the answer is: put your modules on a USB key and copy them to the other system).

#### the best way

The best way of course would be to install Python properly on the other system using setup. But as you said, all dependencies/external libraries that you could easily get using `pip` for instance would have to be re-done. Nothing impossible with a small batch script, even if you don't have internet, but you would have to get hold of all the `.whl` files.

#### the full treatment, portable-style

But if you cannot you can create a "portable" version of python like this:

1. zip the contents of `C:\python27` to an USB key
2. copy all python DLLS: `copy C:\windows\system32\py*DLL K:` (if K is your usb drive)
3. unzip the contents of the archive somewhere on the second machine
4. add the DLLs directly in the `python27` directory.

(those DLLs were installed in the windows system in previous Python versions, now it's even simpler since they are natively installed in the python directory)

The advantage of this method is that it can be automated to be performed on several machines.

There are some disadvantages too:

- python is not seen as "installed" in the registry, so no "uninstall" is proposed. It's a portable install
- associations with `.py` and `.pyw` are not done. But you can do it manually by altering some registry keys.

#### another method, better

You can have best of both worlds like this:

- perform a basic install of python on the second machine
- overwrite the install with the zip file

=> you get the registered install + the associations + the PATH... I would recommend that last method.

#### Last partial method, maybe best matching your question

Try copying the `Lib` directory only. It's where the libraries are installed. I'm not 100% sure but it worked for me when I wanted to put `wx` on a python install lacking `wx`.

Of course you will copy over already existing files, but they are the same so no problem. I let other people comment if this is acceptable or not. I'm not sure of all the installation mechanism, maybe that will fail in some particular case.

Comment: In this case you are specifying to copy a whole python installation. What if I just want to copy python modules from one system to another. Would that also require that the whole python installation is copied over ?

Comment: I'd advise that because it's simpler. That's not a big problem, just a speed issue because python is big. But saves the `sort out updated files` time.

Comment: Could also explain the way I could just copy modules from one system to another in the post above? Since thats what I am actually asking about in this thread. However, its great that you explained how a python installation could be copied from one system to another.

Comment: I added a last chapter to try answering your question.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is the 'copy C:\windows\system32\py*DLL' part. What's with the asterisk? I don't have anything py DLL in my Sys 32.... Also, does this work for 3+? You specified the 27 folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, copy-pasting python installation didn't do the job.

You need to check the "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python*" folder. You may find installed python modules there. Copy and paste these into your source folder will add these modules to your python.